# Convert Geometry to Geography against PostGIS with Npgsql and EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, postgis, npgsql

In PostgreSQL PostGIS I can get the distance in meters by just casting the geometry column to geography using this syntax inside the sql query "**geometry_column::geography**". like so :

```
select * from "Tags" where ST_Distance("Location",'POINT(31.233334 30.033333)'::geography) < 1000 ;
```

Now I want to convert **tag.Location** and **point** to Geography inside the where function of Linq to get the same result.

```
var tags = db.Tags.Where((tag) => tag.Location.Distance(point) < RangeInMeters )
                .Select(tag => new {
                    Id = tag.Id,
                    Title = tag.Title,
                    Coordinates = new double[]{tag.Location.X,tag.Location.Y},
                });
```

here's tag.Location definition

```
[Column(TypeName="geometry (point)")]
public Point Location{get;set;}
```

and here's "point" variable definition

```
var point = new Point(new Coordinate(Longitude,Latitude));
point.SRID = 4326;
```

Comment: There's no `just` in that cast. `geography` contains coordinates on a sphere while `geometry` on a plane. You need to *project* from the sphere to a plane and vice versa. NTS alone doesn't include projections and makes this quite explicit in the docs page. That cast *doesn't* calculate distances though. What's the *actual* PostgreSQL query you used? To calculate distances you need two points

Comment: `inside the where function of Linq to get the same result.` the same as what query? LINQ queries aren't executed directly, they'r converted to SQL queries. What query are you trying to generate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use something like this query to get the points that are within  a range of meters ...
select * from "Tags" where ST_Distance("Location",'POINT(31.233334 30.033333)'::geography) < 1000 ; ..... the challenge is I want to tell linq to do something like "::geography" inside the sql query.

Comment: Change the column attribute to `[Column(TypeName="geography")]`

Answer (score 0):

Change the column attribute to `[Column(TypeName="geography")]`. You don't need a cast if the point is already a geography. Check the examples in [Spatial Mapping with NetTopologySuite](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nts.html#geography-geodetic-support).

From the doc example :

```
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="geography")]
    public Point Location { get; set; }
}

var nearbyCities = context.Cities.Where(c => c.Location.Distance(somePoint) < 100);
```

You can create a geography point directly with `ST_GeographyFromText`. From the [PostGIS geography docs](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geography.html), you can calculate the distance between two points in meters with :

```
SELECT ST_Distance(
  ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-118.4079 33.9434)'), -- Los Angeles (LAX)
  ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(2.5559 49.0083)')     -- Paris (CDG)
  );
```

This returns :

```
9124665.26917268
```

Or 9124Km

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried that and it worked however changing the type to Geography will make me lose some features like getting the X and Y of the Point , as you can see in the Linq statement I have "tag.Location.X" , this will throw an exception if the point is geography,

Comment: Unfortunately ST_GeographyFromText doesn't exist in Npgsql as I know

Comment: `ST_GeographyFromText` is a PostGIS function that should be used instead of the cast. The query I posted comes from the PostGIS docs

Comment: as you can see here https://npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/nts.html `ST_GeographyFromText` is not supported in ngpsql and I want to use Linq instead of plain sql queries.

Comment: The function is from **PostGIS** not NpgSQL. In your SQL you didn't have to use `'POINT(31.233334 30.033333)'::geography`, you could have used `ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(31.233334 30.033333)')`. It looks like the only question is how to retrieve the coordinates on the client, not how to cast